# Playlist.xml custom playlist Path Issue

Tags: php, xml

Okay, basically the issue I'm having is that I have a file called `Playlist.xml` which contains my rtmp stream path however I need the stream to change depending on what room is playing so on load it it edits the path of the stream so for example In PHP I would do this by using the `_GET` function and then echo out the username in the rtmp path however the issue I have is that that the `Playlist.xml` is loaded in the `.swf file` and that the document isn't `.php`, so what could I do to in regards to the `.xml file` to grab the username of the profile that I'm on.

**Playlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist>
  <playitem caption="username" path="rtmp://111.11.11.111/live/username" image="FirstFrame.jpg" options="" clickurl="" clicktarget="_blank" endurl="" styleoftarget="browser" endtarget="">
    <watermarkitem position="00:00:00:000" duration="00:00:00:000" videotype="image" filepath="/logo.png" clickurl="" clicktarget="_blank" fadein="0" fadeout="0" origin="top-left" offsetleft="10" offsettop="11" width="200" height="20" transparency="94" options=""/>
  </playitem>
</playlist>
```

So the problem lays on this part of the document;

```
path="rtmp://111.11.11.111/live/username"
```

where I need the `username` to have the username of the room I'm viewing, How would this be achieved? Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this.

First, init `DOMDocument`, load your XML and init `DOMXPath`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
```

Then, select all `path` attributes of `playitem` nodes:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//playlist/playitem/@path' );
```

At the end, process each node and — through a `preg_replace()` call — add usernames to an array:

```
$usernames = array();
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $usernames[] = preg_replace( '{^.+/([^/]+)$}','\1',$node->nodeValue );
}
```

Now, in `$usernames` array you have all the usernames.

<kbd>**[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/faOmb)**</kbd>

Regular expression explanation:

```
^           Start of string
.+          zero-or-more undefined characters
/           a slash
([^/]+)     group 1: one-or-more not-slash characters
$           End of string
```

---

- See more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- See more about [DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- See more about [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Thankyou so much for this answer have no idea how to use this but now I have the basics I can find out how to implement this into my code thankyou very much. very useful

Comment: @Peanuts Please note that if the XML tree is different than your XML example, the xpath query could not work! Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) to understand xpath syntax.